# Deletion not working in split and join a string in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, join, split

I am using one text box and one paragraph in HTML. When giving empty space in a text box an underscore is adding in the paragraph by using split and join concept, but my problem is when delete text box letters one by one, last letter is not deleted. This is happen because of split and join concept, by removing split-join concept it's working fine, but I need split-join concept as well as deletion.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input id="nameid" ng-change="test()" ng-model="firstname" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Name" required>
</div>
<p>{{editedname}}</p>

<script>
    $scope.test= function (scope) {
        var edtname= $scope.firstname.split(' ').join('_');
        $scope.editedname = edtname;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: where is your controller???

Comment: Hi @soosmca thanks for for your quick reply, my form having controller and i mentioned in my program not in this, do u need it

Comment: we want all code from you

Comment: why you unwanted pass the argument in $scope.test function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that due to `required` validator on input field, model `firstname` becomes `undefined` if the field is empty, thus throwing an error when split is called on `undefined`.

You can simply check if string is `undefined` and if so fallback to empty string `$scope.firstname || ''`:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function(scope) {
    var edtname = ($scope.firstname || '').split(' ').join('_');
    $scope.editedname = edtname;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input id="nameid" ng-keyup="test()" ng-model="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
    </div>
    <p>{{editedname}}</p>
</div>
```